# Substitution of characters in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I am working on doubling all vowels in every word. For eg:

```
$string="if it rains, cover with umbrella";
```

Here is the code I wrote, but I am not getting correct output.

```
$string=~s/a|e|i|o|u/aa|ee|ii|oo|uu/gi; print $string;
```

Expected Output: `iif iit raaiins cooveer wiith uumbreelaa`

Can some one help me in this?

Comment: Welcome to SO! This is a very good first (ish) post! One thing that I would say to improve, however, is include the incorrect output. This will help people identify what's wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The regular expression in your substitution should work fine but, as you will have seen, the replacement string is a simple string that bears no relation to the match unless you capture substrings within the regular expression and use them in the replacement string.

Use a character class to match any one of a set of characters, like `[aeiuo]`.

Use parentheses to 'capture' part of a match, so that you can use it in the replacement string.

```
my $string = "if it rains, cover with umbrella";

$string =~ s/([aeiuo])/$1$1/g;

print $string;
```

**output**

```
iif iit raaiins, cooveer wiith uumbreellaa
```

Answer (score 3):

All matches are captured in variables $1,...,$9, so if you substitute $1 twice it will repeat whatever the match is, in this case it will double up vowels

```
$string=~ s/(a|e|i|o|u)/\1\1/gi; 
print $string;
```

Comment: It is bad form to use `\1` etc. in the replacement string. See [Warning on \1 Instead of $1](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Warning-on-\1-Instead-of-$1). Also, multiple one-character alternations are crying out to be written as a character class `[aeiuo]`

Answer (score 1):

As previously mentioned, the following would do the trick in this circumstance:

```
s/([aeiuo])/$1$1/ig;    # A => AA
```

Or maybe you want

```
s/([aeiuo])/\L$1$1/ig;  # A => aa
```

The following is an alternative solution that works for arbitrary translation maps:

```
my %map = (
   'a' => 'aa',
   'e' => 'ee',
   'i' => 'ii',
   'o' => 'uu',
   'u' => 'oo',
);

my $pat =
   join '|',
    map quotemeta,
     sort { length($b) <=> length($a) }
      keys(%map);

s/($pat)/$map{$1}/g;
```

The above even works if you have

```
( 'foo' => 'bar',
  'bar' => 'foo' )
```

The `sort` line can be omitted if you don't have something like

```
( 'foo'  => 'bar',
  'food' => 'baz' )
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't print what the incorrect output was, but you can simply replace each vowel with its double. For example:

```
$string =~ s/a/aa/g;
$string =~ s/e/ee/g;
$string =~ s/i/ii/g;
$string =~ s/o/oo/g;
$string =~ s/u/uu/g;
```